# Only check for raycaster intersection only once on each button click in A Frame

Tags: javascript, aframe

I have an on screen shoot button.

```
<div style="text-align:center;height: 50px;" >
      <button id="shootbutton" style="float: right;height: 50px;width: 100px;font-size : 19px;background-color:red;">SHOOT</button>
    </div>
```

And a player entity.

```
 <a-entity id="player" 
            raycaster 
            raycast-score 
            raycast-death 
            networked="template:#avatar-template;showLocalTemplate:false;" 
            camera spawn-in-circle="radius:3;" 
            position="0 1.3 0" 
            wasd-controls 
            look-controls 
            touch-move-controls 
            twoway-motion="speed: 35"
            >
  </a-entity>
```

I would like the raycaster to only check for intersections only once each time the the shoot button is pressed.

```
<script>
    var score = 0;

    AFRAME.registerComponent('raycast-score', {
      init: function() {
        var that = this;
        document.getElementById("shootbutton").onclick = function(e){
            that.shoot();
        }
      },


      shoot: function() {
        function evt () {
          score++ ;
          console.log("Score: " + score)

    }
          this.el.addEventListener('raycaster-intersection', evt)
          this.el.removeEventListener('raycaster-intersection', evt)
      },
    });


  </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

**If you want to know only if there is any intersection**

Use the event listeners to store the information whether your ray is intersecting or not, and check it within the `shoot()` function:

```
...
init: function() {
  this.isIntersecting = false
  this.el.addEventListener("raycaster-intersection", (e) => {
    this.isIntersecting = true
  }
  this.el.addEventListener("raycaster-intersection-cleared", (e) => {
    this.isIntersecting = false
  }
},
shoot: function() {
  if (this.isIntersecting) {
     // the raycaster is intersecting 
  }
...
```

**If you want detail which entity you're intersecting with:**

You can check with which elements the raycaster is intersecting with the `intersectedEls` property of the component:

```
rayEl.components['raycaster'].intersectedEls
```

When your button is clicked, you can grab the entities from there.

```
shoot: function() {
  // do something with this.el.components['raycaster'].intersectedEls
}
```

Fiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/xd0eLsbw/).

---

If you want the raycaster entity to actively check for intersections only on click, you can set the raycasters `enabled` property to true only when you need it. Although the raycaster needs a while, hence my timeout.

```
shoot() {
   ray.setAttribute("raycaster", "enabled", "true")
   setTimeout((e)=> {
     console.log(ray.components['raycaster'].intersectedEls)
     ray.setAttribute("raycaster", "enabled", "false")
   }, 500)
}
```

Fiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/xd0eLsbw/2/).

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Is it possible to only check for an intersection once, when the button is clicked, then stop?

Comment: Why not checking on `shoot()` whether there are any intersected elements `rayEl.components['raycaster'].intersectedEls.length === 0` ?

Comment: Thanks. However, what I need is for the raycaster to check for an intersection one time when the shoot button is pressed, then stop checking for intersections (as if one single shot is fired).  Right now, the raycaster continues to check for intersections every frame, and doesn't stop. I'll keep trying, and post when I come up with a way.

Comment: @DimitriBaubooa check my update, you can enable the raycaster when necessary, and then disable it. Let me know if it works for you

Comment: Thanks. The raycaster now stops checking for intersections after the set interval. However the `  this.el.setAttribute("raycaster")` doesn't add the raycaster to the element (it works the first time only, if a raycaster was added to the element in HTML to begin with). Full function: `shoot: function () {

  this.el.setAttribute("raycaster")


  this.el.addEventListener('raycaster-intersection', function (evt) {
  
  score++ ;
  console.log("Score: " + score)
  
  setTimeout((e)=> {
  this.removeAttribute("raycaster")
  },10)

  });
},
`

Comment: i was trying to avoid adding and removing the `raycaster` enitity, I believe it will be very 'heavy' when there will be more stuff on the website.

Answer (score 0):

You can disable the raycaster (maybe only on master? I forgot) so it doesn't run on every frame or interval:

```
el.setAttribute('raycaster', 'enabled', false);
```

Then check for intersection manually after a tap. The `rayOrigin: mouse` with a touch will move the raycaster appropriate and after which you can check.

```
// Manually check intersection.
el.components.raycaster.checkIntersections();
```